# How create a bootable rescue partition on a remote machine to ssh in case of boot error?

Tags: boot

Basically is it possible at all and if it is, how to do it. I need to access a remote machine in case of boot errors to fix them using for example fsck when all partitions should be unmounted etc.

Comment: A Persistent or Full install USB should be able to do the job.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that I don't have physical access to the remote PC, only through Teamviewer